# php check range in range

Tags: php, date, range

I'm trying to check if a date range (converted to Unix timestamp) is within a saved date range. The purpose is to see if a product subscription already purchased or in a customers cart clashes with a newly selected item.

I can test a 'date' within a date range but not show how to approach checking for a range in a range..??

For instance the following code will tell whether an entered date is within a test date range:

```
<?php 
$startDate = strtotime("10/12/2014"); 
$endDate = strtotime("10/25/2014"); 
 ?>


<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$targetDate = strtotime($_POST['testDate']);


    if (($targetDate >= $startDate) && ($targetDate <= $endDate)) {
    $showMe = 'trueness';
}
else {
    $showMe = 'false';
      }
}
?>

 <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
 <input type="text" id="testDate" name="testDate" value="<?php echo date("m-d-Y", $targetDate); ?>">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"><?php echo date("m-d-Y", $targetDate); ?>
</form>



<p><?php echo 'Result: '. $showMe; ?></p>
```

Basically we can check a date to see if it is in a date range but how to check if two separate date ranges intersect?

Comment: try using this condition `range2.start >= range1.start && range2.end <= range1.end` => range2 in range1 (pseudo code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two sets of date ranges ($startDate to $endDate and $targetStartDate to $targetEndDate), this is how to check for intersection...

```
    if ($targetEndDate >= $startDate && $targetStartDate <= $endDate)
    {
        $showMe = 'trueness';
    }
    else 
    {
        $showMe = 'false';
    }
```

You can adjust the >= and <= if there is a special case where you don't consider it intersecting if they only intersect on the start/end date.